# What does "GG GL" means, and how can I use it?

Tags: online, terminology

For example, I know that "GL HF" means "Good luck and have fun". Also, I often see in online poker room that the answer to the acronym "GG FH" is "GG GL". But what "GG GL" is means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just used in poker, but it means "good game, good luck"

Answer (score 2):

I find it is often used in online poker games as an underhanded insult rather than a realistic expression of friendship.